# Ionic 2 Add Custom build script

Tags: ionic-framework, npm, ionic2

I am using Ionic 2 via CLI. In this version they use NPM SCRIPTS as opposed to gulp.

```
   "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
 },
```

I have read about adding custom scripts to the config but am not clear how to do this. this is my current config...

```
"config": {
    "ionic_bundler": "webpack",
    "ionic_source_map": "source-map",
    "ionic_source_map_type": "eval"
  },
```

I need to create a custom script called "replace" It will be using NPM replace. How can I add this so that when I run ionic serve or build it will run?

Here is the gulp code I want to run.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var replace = require('gulp-string-replace');
var p = require('./package.json');
var version = p.version;
gulp.task('serve:after', ['version']);

console.log('Task init!!!');
gulp.task('version', function() {
  gulp.src(["./www/index.html"])
  .pipe(replace(/VERSION/g, p.version))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./www/'));
});
```

Comment: Guess I'll have to answer this myself one day haha

Comment: do you want to use the npm replace or your own custom replace?

Comment: Npm replace I just need to replace version in a file prior to build right now am am manually running gulp replace string

Comment: provide that gulp code how you are doing so that it would be easy to accomidate in the npm

Comment: I added my gulp code to original question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ionic CLI (v3.X) goes directly to `gulpfile.js` and looks for [CLI hooks](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/#cli-hooks).

**ionic serve**:

```
gulp.task('ionic:watch:before', function() {
  console.log("this is run before 'ionic serve'");
});
```

**ionic build:**

```
gulp.task('ionic:build:before', function() {
  console.log("this is run before 'ionic build'");
});
```

so you should add something like this to your `gulpfile.js`:

```
gulp.task('ionic:watch:before', ['version']);
gulp.task('ionic:build:before', ['version']);
```

Answer (score 1):

To simply run your gulp task just add it to your package.json.

```
"scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
--> "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build && gulp serve:after",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "watch": "ionic-app-scripts watch"
}
```

Note: this will not work if you put the "&& gulp" after ionic:serve - the gulp task will wait for the first part to finish, but ionic serve will start up a dev server and stay running so the second part never executes.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to run your Gulp Task from NPM

Add the [gulp-npm-script-sync](https://github.com/austinpray/gulp-npm-script-sync)  as follows `npm install --save-dev gulp-npm-script-sync`

Now we need to sync this gulp task to the `package.json` as follows

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sync = require('gulp-npm-script-sync');

// your gulpfile contents

sync(gulp);
```

Every time you update your gulpfile with a new task it will update your package.json.

You can even throw it inside a gulp task:

```
gulp.task('sync', function () {
  sync(gulp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you have to copy and existing task that you want to modify and paste in your source code /project/task. Then add your task in that file. and change package.json to overwrite ionic 2 default config.

```
"config": {
    "ionic_cleancss": "./task/cleancss.config.js"
  },
```

More info :
https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts#custom-configuration